# Google Spreadsheet Connector Issue: Unable to get valid certificate path to requested Google API OAUTH2 target

Tags: oauth-2.0, certificate, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

Having problems with google-spreadsheets:authorize.  The exact error received is the following when going through the oauth2callback...
500 Server Error.  Message - Unable to fetch access token.

Local Dev Environment:

- Mule ESB 3.9
- JDK 1.8_161
- Google Spreadsheet Connector 1.2.4

http://localhost:3000/oauth2callback?state=*some_generated_state_value*&code=*some_generated_code*

[image]

```
<google-spreadsheets:config-with-oauth name="Google_Spreadsheets" consumerKey="${google.apiKey}" consumerSecret="${google.apiSecret}" doc:name="Google Spreadsheets">
        <google-spreadsheets:oauth-callback-config domain="localhost" localPort="3000" remotePort="3000" path="oauth2callback"/>
</google-spreadsheets:config-with-oauth>

<flow name="authorizationAndAuthenticationFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="httpListenerConfig" path="${google.api}/oauth-authorize" allowedMethods="GET" doc:name="HTTP" >
        </http:listener>
        <google-spreadsheets:authorize config-ref="Google_Spreadsheets" accessTokenUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" authorizationUrl="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth" doc:name="Google Spreadsheets"/>

        <logger message="Google has authorized the connector." level="INFO" doc:name="Logger: Log Google authorization"/>

        <set-payload value="You have successfully authorized the connector" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

The exact stack trace error is below...

```
ERROR 2018-02-08 19:35:25,195 [[app-google].auto-generated-listener-config-0.worker.01] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Unable to fetch access token.
Payload               : {NullPayload}
Payload Type          : org.mule.transport.NullPayload
Element               : /DynamicFlow-localhost:3000\/oauth2callback/processors/0/1 @ app-google
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141)
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:392)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:302)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1596)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1052)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:987)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1072)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1334)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1309)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:259)
    at org.mule.security.oauth.util.HttpUtilImpl.post(HttpUtilImpl.java:72)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue.  I'm not sure if it's a connector source code issue or an issue with Google potentially changing their OAUTH2 API implementation in v4.  Either way the stack trace seems to be clear with TLS certificate issues.  Maybe need to provide the google api certificate, so any idea on how to inject a truststore used by the application or JVM to get passed this certifcate issue?

Answer (score 0):

My java installation was not installed correctly after re-imaging my system.  Reinstalled JDK 1.8_161 and it fixed the certificate issue.